# Image gallery is not working well

Tags: html, css

I have a problem on my portfolio [website](http://www.oprant.com/FK/#!/page_works).

```
DETAYLI BILGI > English Language > More Details

<div class="img1" id="active">
    <img src="images/big_img.jpg" alt="">
    <a href="#!/cendla" class="link1"><span></span>detaylı bilgi</a>
</div>
<div class="img2">
    <img src="images/big_img1.jpg" alt="">
    <a href="#!/oprant" class="link1"><span></span>detaylı bilgi</a>
</div>
<div class="img3">
    <img src="images/big_img2.jpg" alt="">
    <a href="#!/cendla" class="link1"><span></span>detaylı bilgi</a>
</div>
```

They are all links to pages like :

```
/oprant
/cendla
```

But the last `div menu (img 15) is /kadisozluk` and it is showing `ALL IMAGE GALLERYS to /kadisozluk`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The link to your website sends me to an error page - "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found". Add a proper link, otherwise there is no way of helping you with the little code you provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link to your webpage does not work. Please check the spelling of your href, it may be easier to copy and paste the file name of the new page to the href.

You may want to validate your page using w3 validator and it may help you remove any errors on your page.

I cannot diagnose the problem due as you need to provide more information and code.